# NSum generates a warning message when getting the sum of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics

I know what I'm doing can be done with `Total`:

```
a = Range@3;
Total@a
```

And  if I simply choose `Sum`, nothing wrong will happen:

```
a = Range@3;
Sum[a[[i]], {i, 3}]
```

`N@Sum` is still OK:

```
a = Range@3;
N@Sum[a[[i]], {i, 3}]
```

But when it's changed to `NSum`, a warning message comes out though I still get the correct result:

```
a = Range@3;
NSum[a[[i]], {i, 3}]
```

> Part::pspec: Part specification i is neither an integer nor a list of
>   integers.

I found if I add a `Hold`, I can avoid the warning:

```
a = Range@3;
NSum[Hold@a[[i]], {i, 3}]
```

But I still want to know the exact reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I assumed was that the `Hold*` attributes of the functions must be different, but they both have the attributes `HoldAll`.

On the other hand, the algorithms behind `Sum` and `NSum` are quite different.  I certainly don't know all the details but we can examine what's going on with `TracePrint`.

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
TracePrint[NSum[a[[i]], {i, 3}], _Part]

(* Print result:
    a[[i]]
    {1,2,3}[[i]]
*)
```

Note that `Part` is called with a symbolic argument `i`.  Now, let's do it with `Sum`.

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
TracePrint[Sum[a[[i]], {i, 3}], _Part]

(* Print result:
  a[[i]]
  {1,2,3}[[1]]

  a[[i]]
  {1,2,3}[[2]]

  a[[i]]
  {1,2,3}[[3]]
*)
```

I suspect that `NSum` is attempting to do some symbolic evaluations of the summand.

Comment: "I suspect that `NSum[]` is attempting to do some symbolic evaluations of the summand." - looking at `TracePrint[NSum[a[[k]], {k, 3}], TraceInternal -> True]`, it apparently does; it tries to compile `a[[i]]`...

Comment: @J.M. I think `NSum[ ]` is calling `NIntegrate[]` try for example  `NSum[1/k^2, {k, 1, 10^100}]`

Comment: @bel, that too (well, either of `Integrate[]` or `NIntegrate[]`); `NSum[]`'s default method is Euler-Maclaurin, which does involve the integration of the summand...

Comment: @J.M. "TraceInternal"…it's another option that isn't described clearly in the help, right? And… oh, the output with it is so complex…

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that NSum[ ] wants to have a function as its first argument (and not a list). So if we supply a function

```
 a[x_]:=x;
```

to mimic your Range command, and you can NSum without warning using

```
 NSum[a[i], {i, 3}]
```

or more concisely

```
 NSum[i, {i, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: Um… “a function as its first argument”,…not exactly, I think. `Part` is also a function, right?